# Convert a 2-D Array into a Array Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a 2-D Array into a Array

`array = [["red","green"],["red","yellow"]]`

to that:

`a = ["red","green","red","yellow"]`

And it should also be a solution for bigger arrays

Comment: Those are `lists` not `arrays`, and this is a noteworthy difference which is important to understand when developing python code.